# Real Lagrangian with complex variable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, calculus

I have a general question concerning real valued Lagrangians that take complex arguments. I have seen in many works of physicists and lecture books where extremal problems are discussed in Lagrangians that are real but depend on complex fields.

But, according to the Cauchy-Riemann equations, a real function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is only differentiable, when $f=const.$ since it has no imaginary part, i.e., for $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ (with $v(x,y)=0$) it is
$$
\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y}=0\qquad \frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x}=0\, .
$$
Obviously, most Lagrangians are not constants, so I am wondering, how extremal problems, optimisations or Taylor series make even sense? How are these types of calculations consistent with mathematics? And how does one Taylor expand real Lagrangians with complex variables?

Comment: Complex-analytic $\neq$ real-differentiable. $L=x-iy$ is not holomorphic but its (real) partial derivatives are perfectly well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex variables in physics are often real differentiable (=smooth) but rarely complex differentiable (=holomorphic/analytic). The simplest example in field theory is a complex scalar field.

Comment: I see, makes sense. So a real Lagrangian with complex arguments is Taylor expanded by separating the arguments in real and imaginary parts and then take the real derivatives?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. With the usual caveat that a Taylor expansion needs not be convergent.